# new react-native 0.43.3 project Element Type in invalid error

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

If I create a new folder app and inside it create index.js file which is a simple React component rendering text Hello world i.e

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Hello WOrld
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and then in index.ios.js I call:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import Test from './app'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test)
```

I get the error that Element type is invalid:

> expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function but
>   got object.

However If I create the component within the index.ios.js the component renders fine.

My app folder structure:

```
Test
 app
  index.js
 index.ios.js
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked was `import Test from './app/index';`